# SharedViewModels and the onCleared method

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

Android jetpack advocates sharing data between fragments via SharedViewModels as shown in the official documentation at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

It is a simple technique in which a ViewModel is bound to the hosting activity and the fragments all retrieve the same instance of it and there by communicate.

However one important note that has not been addressed is what would be the impact of this on the memory?. If two fragments that used a viewmodel bound to the activity are both destroyed , that ViewModel would still be alive and possibly have LiveData in it too taking up precious space .

Any patterns to properly implement SharedViewModels?

Comment: True! If your ViewModels are too heavy then you should implement this some other way. But curious, with persistent data in DB/ SharedPrefs how much space does a ViewModel take anyway?

Comment: Arka I am unsure myself. Like for example if I have a list of students that are paged , all of them would be stored in the livedata member of the viewmodel. 

so if i have pulled out 500 students , all of them would be in the livedata :O. for the entire span of the application.

Comment: Well since ViewModel is in this case tied to the activity, so they will be in memory as long as the activity is on destroyed. Yeah, I wouldn't implement an app with single activity in such scenario. I would tie the ViewModel to the fragments as much as possible.